# Getting dependency issues on configuring dpkg

Tags: dpkg

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package python-debian (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier-common:
 update-notifier-common depends on python-debian; however:
  Package python-debian is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt-xapian-index:
 apt-xapian-index depends on python-debian (>= 0.1.14); however:
  Package python-debian is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apt-xapian-index (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
 flashplugin-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon:
 python-aptdaemon dependNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                            s on python-debian; however:
  Package python-debian is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on python-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-center:
 software-center depends on python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 software-center depends on python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets; however:
  Package python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sessioninstaller:
 sessioninstaller depends on python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets; however:
  Package python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sessioninstaller (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am getting this error when i am trying to configure dpkg...
please tell me what to do..i am stuck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is obviously something wrong with your dpkg. 
Run this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

this will make dpkg repairs itself

Then run your installations again.

If it doesn't work run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and again

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This should do the trick

Comment: "dpkg: error processing package python-debian (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration" this actually doesn't fix this issue, which is why the dependencies are failing.

Comment: I have similar issues, but none of these solutions worked. I feel like being in the 90's, when one had to do a reinstall on a regular basis...

Comment: I got my dpkg/apt completely destroyed after I accidently killed apt during install then everything was broken, forcing app nor any dpkg fix broken was warking nothing - only thing that work was purge the damaged packages through **dpkg** according to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1383417/277898 `dpkg -l | grep ^iU | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge` only after that I was able to make apt working again